# Authenticating Custom User Model for Login Django

Tags: python, django

I created my custom user model in my Django project. My user registering works properly. However, my login is not.

This is my custom user model:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class NewUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=150, primary_key = True)
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    nombreArtistico = models.CharField(max_length=150, default=None, null=True, unique=True)

    #Validacion create_superuser
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_active   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff    = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    #Info de la suscripcion_form
    activa = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    fecha_creacion = models.DateField(default=None, null=True)
    fecha_actualizacion = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    disponibilidad_de_reproducciones = models.IntegerField(default=3)

    # objects = CustomAccountManager()

     USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['firstName', 'lastName']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

This is my Authentication Login Form:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from usuarios.models import NewUser
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class Register(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label="username", max_length=150)
    firstName = forms.CharField(label="First Name", max_length=150)
    lastName = forms.CharField(label="Last Name", max_length=150)
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", max_length=150, widget=forms.PasswordInput)

class AuthenticationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label="username", max_length=150)
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", max_length=150, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

This is what I am trying in my login view.

```
def login_view(response):
if response.method == "POST":
    print(response.POST['username'])
    form = AuthenticationForm(response.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username  = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password  = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        userauth = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if userauth is not None:
            login(response, user1)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')

    #return redirect()
else:
    form = AuthenticationForm()
return render(response, 'login/login.html', {"form2":AuthenticationForm()})
```

This is the error I am getting. My guess is that the function authenticate() that I am using is not being related to my custom user model.

[error_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/losFN.png)

Something important to say is that I redefined my user model, as follows:
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'usuarios.NewUser'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a custom user model but you haven't created it's manager like how all the other models are handled in django. Try building from on [this full example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) from the official [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#).

### It's important to note that

If you only need to extend the default User model consider inheriting from the [AbstractUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user) and inheriting from  [AbstractBaseUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) if you want further customization.